# Differential Equation $4(x-2)^2\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y-1)^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to proceed with the following differential equation?

$$4(x-2)^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(x+y-1)^2$$

Can this be solved with separable variable method after some substitution.

Trying to substitute $(x+y-1) = v$ does not seem to help.

Any ideas?

==========**Edit**==========

With the help of [Jaideep's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/421580/jaideep-khare) answer, I think following is how to proceed further :

$$u\frac{dk}{du}=\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}-k$$
$$\Rightarrow u\frac{dk}{du}=\frac{(k-1)^2}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dk}{(k-1)^2}=\frac{du}{4u}$$
$$Integrating,\ \frac{-1}{(k-1)}=\frac{\log u}{4} + \frac{\log c}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow \log c(x-2)=\frac{4(2-x)}{y-x+1}$$

I think this is correct, but I am not able to understand how [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4(x-2)%5E2(dy%2Fdx)%3D(x%2By-1)%5E2) got its solution.

Comment: Which variable are you solving for?

Comment: Solving for y... basically i want a general solution to this differential equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $x-2=u$ and $y+1=v$. Your differential equation will reduce to -

$$4(u)^2 \cdot\dfrac{dv}{du}=(u+v)^2 $$

Now this is homogeneous type of differential equation.

Substitute $v=ku$

$$v=ku \implies \frac{dv}{du}=u \frac{dk}{du}+k $$

Your differential equation reduces to

$$u\frac{dk}{du}+k=\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}$$

Now this variable separable form after moving $k$ from LHS to RHS.

Comment: Thanks. After expanding (k+1)^2, there is one constant term (1/4). I am not able to fit this constant into Bernoulli Differential equation form.

Comment: @simajinid Sorry, it wasn't Bernoulli. It's variable separable form. I have edited my answer.